# Why does an unloaded image without the float property not have its specified height and width (but with the float property it does?)

Tags: image, css-float, codepen

[Code-pen link](https://codepen.io/-zilliz-/pen/XWPPJzm)

In the above link, I have an image (without a valid value for the src attribute) and some text nested with in a  element:

```
<img src="" alt="Yellow Lady Slipper" height="100" width="100" border= "3px">
```

I have this set up duplicated, but with the image floated left with the following class selector:

```
.float { float: left;
         margin-right: 10px;
         border: 3px ridge #000000; }

<img class="float" src="blank" alt="Yellow Lady Slipper" height="100" width="100">
```

In the case with no float, the image 'placeholder' has a height/width specified by how much alt-text there is.

But in the case with the float, the 'placeholder' height/width is as specified in the img tag.

I wouldn't expect whether an image 'placeholder' is part of the normal flow or not would have a bearing on its height/width?

When I provide a valid value for the src attribute, the height/width behaves as expected as is identical in both scenarios. Just curious as to why this isn't the case when the image doesn't load/isn't valid.

Comment: And does it display correctly if the src is valid ?

Comment: Well, the thing is the src attribute is invalid for both the 'no float' and 'with float' scenarios. But in the 'with float' scenario, the image still doesn't load (which is what I would expect anyway), but the height and width of the img element is displayed correctly (unlike in the 'no float' case, where it doesn't, which is not what I'd expect).

Comment: They are both error conditions. Whatever you are expecting is unrealistic.

Answer (score 0):

The **src** attribute is required.  This means that without **src**, the HTML is invalid and meaningless.  The why then becomes moot.  Different browsers may act differently in such a situation.

> The **src** attribute is required, and contains the path to the image you want to embed.
> The **alt** attribute holds a text description of the image, which isn't mandatory but is incredibly

> **Image loading errors**
> If an error occurs while loading or rendering an image, and an onerror event handler has been set for the error event, that event handler will get called. This can happen in several situations, including:
>
> - The src attribute is empty ("") or null.
> - The src URL is the same as the URL of the page the user is currently on.
> - The image is corrupted in some way that prevents it from being loaded.
> - The image's metadata is corrupted in such a way that it's impossible to retrieve its dimensions, and no dimensions were specified in the  element's attributes.
> - The image is in a format not supported by the user agent.

From [developer.mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Img)